# Android: How to find the nearest neighbor (View Element) in a given direction

Tags: android, view, focus, find, nearest-neighbor

I'm searching a method to navigate in a app throw all elements with a virtual dpad. But how do I find the nearest neighbor in the directions up, down, left and right?
e.g I have an event received to go down, now I want to set the focus on the button below.

I don't want to use the definition in the xml files like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" ... >

    <Button android:id="@+id/top" android:nextFocusUp="@+id/bottom" ... />
    <Button android:id="@+id/bottom" android:nextFocusDown="@+id/top" ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I do that?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the smart solution (e.g for go down):

```
bic=new BaseInputConnection(this.getWindow().getDecorView(),false);
KeyEvent event2 = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN,0, KeyEvent.META_SYM_ON, 0, 0, KeyEvent.FLAG_VIRTUAL_HARD_KEY); 

bic.sendKeyEvent(event2);
```

Thats all, an internal algortihm find the next element in your selected direction

Answer (score 0):

For this you should override `onKeyDown()` method in `Activity`, there you can find currently focused view with method `View.getFocusedChild()`, then use `View.focusSearch(int)` for searching next view, and `View.requestFocus()` for getting focus.

I hope you can combine this methods for good result :)

Comment: i search a methode for a focused element which get me an neighbor element in a specific direction to set the focus on that found elment.

Comment: The problem is the methode View.focusSearch(int), if i try View.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_UP) the application crash. This methode only works if there is following line in the xml on the elements: android:nextFocusUp="@+id/bottom" but i dont want this code in every view on every element.

Comment: i also see that getFocusedChild() is not available on view only on ViewGroups